# Java XML Parse issue

Tags: java, xml

I am facing difficulty in accessing XML value, Can any one let me know what i am missing.

```
String xml = "<Standard p1:oid=\"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000f674c1\"\n" +
                "                               xmlns:p1=\"com.iMelt.metaCore.DataObjects.Core\" xmlns=\"com.iMelt.Car.Model.Core\"\n" +
                "                               reasonCode=\"0\">\n" +
                "    <p1:__info p1:eid=\"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000\">\n" +
                "        <p1:creationDate>2016-05-28T20:33:45.337+00:00</p1:creationDate>\n" +
                "        <p1:lastEditorRef>Administrator</p1:lastEditorRef>\n" +
                "        <p1:version>5</p1:version>\n" +
                "    </p1:__info>\n" +
                "    <ChangeState>Approved</ChangeState></Standard>";

byte[] byteArray = xml.getBytes();
ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true); 
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse(inputStream);
XPathFactory xpathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xpathfactory.newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/Standard/ChangeState");
Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Comment: what sort of difficulty you are facing? what is the exact problem!

Comment: I have tried /ChangeState as well, not populating "Approved" value in result

Comment: your XML is missing the XML deceleration `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Comment: I have tried <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> also but no help.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, is that you don't have nodes called "Standard" and "ChangeState", you have nodes that have namespaced version of Standard and ChangeState.

So you need to use the XPath.setNamespace() method to associate a prefix with a namespace, and then use that prefix in your xpath expressions. Note since you only using the default namespace in your queries, that's all you have to specify, something like

```
   String xml = "<Standard p1:oid=\"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000f674c1\"\n"
            + "                               xmlns:p1=\"com.iMelt.metaCore.DataObjects.Core\" xmlns=\"com.iMelt.Car.Model.Core\"\n"
            + "                               reasonCode=\"0\">\n" + "    <p1:__info p1:eid=\"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000\">\n"
            + "        <p1:creationDate>2016-05-28T20:33:45.337+00:00</p1:creationDate>\n" + "        <p1:lastEditorRef>Administrator</p1:lastEditorRef>\n"
            + "        <p1:version>5</p1:version>\n" + "    </p1:__info>\n" + "    <ChangeState>Approved</ChangeState></Standard>";

    byte[] byteArray = xml.getBytes();
    ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse(inputStream);
    XPathFactory xpathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = xpathfactory.newXPath();
    xpath.setNamespaceContext(new NamespaceContext() {

        @Override
        public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
            return "com.iMelt.Car.Model.Core";
        }

        @Override
        public String getPrefix(String namespaceURI) {

            return "x";
        }

        @Override
        public Iterator getPrefixes(String namespaceURI) {
            return null;
        }

    });
    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/x:Standard/x:ChangeState");
    NodeList result = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

The other, less valid option is to remove the statement

```
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
```

Comment: I have tried both the option xpath.setNamespaceContext and remove factory.setNamespaceAware(true), also but no help

Comment: sorry but this works as is, did you change your xpath expression -- adding the prefixes 'x'?

Comment: Yes its working, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The following code outputs "Approved". I have removed `factory.setNamespaceAware(true);`so that you don't need to specify the default namespace and added code at the end to output the text value.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;

// ...

String xml = "<Standard p1:oid=\"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000f674c1\"\n" +
                "                               xmlns:p1=\"com.iMelt.metaCore.DataObjects.Core\" xmlns=\"com.iMelt.Car.Model.Core\"\n" +
                "                               reasonCode=\"0\">\n" +
                "    <p1:__info p1:eid=\"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000\">\n" +
                "        <p1:creationDate>2016-05-28T20:33:45.337+00:00</p1:creationDate>\n" +
                "        <p1:lastEditorRef>Administrator</p1:lastEditorRef>\n" +
                "        <p1:version>5</p1:version>\n" +
                "    </p1:__info>\n" +
                "    <ChangeState>Approved</ChangeState></Standard>";

byte[] byteArray = xml.getBytes();
ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse(inputStream);
XPathFactory xpathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xpathfactory.newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/Standard/ChangeState");
NodeList result = (NodeList)expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
Node node = result.item(0);
System.out.println(node.getTextContent());
```

Comment: I have tried above , its giving null pointer exception

Comment: You can see here that it runs without error and outputs "Approved": https://ideone.com/JGMiag